# How to link an ActionBar to an Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I created an ActionBar (ToolBar) and I was wondering how to link that ActionBar to a specific Activity (perhaps using onClick)?

Comment: It's always best to show how far you got on your own already.

Comment: What do you mean "onClick"? Where are you clicking?

Answer (score 0):

In any one Activity layout, you can add Toolbar

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        />

    <!-- contents -->

</LinearLayout>
```